# Intercambiar los valores que estan en posiciones pares de una lista por otros de otra lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Acabo de empezar con las listas y estaba buscando la manera de crear una función que me dejase cambiar los elementos que están en las posiciones pares por otros de otra lista alternativa:

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora (pero me pone a 0 los elementos que están en posiciones pares). Me gustaría saber si debería tirar por otro método o si tengo algún fallo en el codigo y por que.
Muchas gracias

```
def pares(lista1, lista2):
    for i in range(0, len(lista1)):
         for j in lista2:
             if i % 2 == 0:
                 lista1[i]=j
    return lista1



list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2=[3, 6, 0] 
print(pares(list, list2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Casi lo tienes! Voy a tomar **tu código como ejemplo para resolver el problema.**

Lo primero es que deberías tomar una decisión previamente, si **quieres permitir listas de distinto tamaño, o no**. En el caso de que tengan el mismo tamaño puedes usar el indice `i` que te has crea con el bucle `for`.

## Listas con mismo tamaño

```
def pares(lista1, lista2):
    #Nos creamos una nueva variable, para evitar sobreescribir lista1 (opcional)
    nueva_lista1 = lista1.copy()

    #Utilizamos assert para que devuelva un error si le pasamos listas de distinto tamaño
    assert len(lista1) == len(lista2), "Las listas han de tener el mismo tamaño"

    #Hago un bucle for que itera por las dos listas
    for i in range(0, len(lista1)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            nueva_lista1[i]= lista2[i]
    return nueva_lista1


list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
#redefino list2 para que tenga el mismo tamaño que list1
list2=[3, 6, 0, 5, 7, 9] 
print(pares(list1, list2))
```

**Salida:**

```
[3, 2, 0, 4, 7, 6]
```

Si obligas a las listas a tener el mismo tamaño, es sencillo con el mismo iterador `i` mediante el indice puedes ir consultando una lista y otra e ir realizando las asignaciones hacia la primera lista.

## Listas con distinto tamaño

Si la lista segunda no tiene el mismo tamaño que la primera, siguiendo con la solución que has implementado, **solo tienes que hacer un condicional** para evitar un `IndexError`, te dejo comentarios en el código:

```
def pares(lista1, lista2):
    #Nos creamos una nueva variable, para evitar sobreescribir lista1 (opcional)
    nueva_lista1 = lista1.copy()

    #Guardamos los tamaños de cada lista
    tamano_lista1 = len(lista1)
    tamano_lista2 = len(lista2)

    #En el caso de que el tamaño de la primera lista sea mayor, solo iteramos hasta el tamaño de la segunda
    if tamano_lista1 > tamano_lista2:
        tamano_iterador = tamano_lista2
    else:
        tamano_iterador = tamano_lista1
    
    for i in range(tamano_iterador):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            lista1[i]= lista2[i]
    return lista1



list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,12,23]
list2=[3, 6, 0] 

print("La lista mayor es la primera: ", pares(list1, list2))
print("La lista mayor es la segunda: ", pares(list2, list1))
```

**Salida:**

```
La lista mayor es la primera:  [3, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 12, 23]
La lista mayor es la segunda:  [1, 6, 3]
```

### Bonus Extra

- El copiar la lista que voy a devolve lo hago, para que la función no me cambie la propia lista que le paso por parámetro, si no que la quede como está.
- En el código adjunto utilizas `list` como variable, cuando `list` es una palabra reservada del lenguaje que **se utiliza para crear listas**. Y aunque Python lo permite, no es una buena práctica redefinir palabras reservadas del lenguaje, ya que induce a confunsión y a errores a la hora de programar para ti, y para otros programadores que vean tu código.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la explicación y por todo!!! Los consejos me han servido de mucho para otros ejercicios y lo he entendido todo muchas gracias!!!

Comment: De nada siempre es un gusto ayudar :) Si te ha servido mis respuesta, la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es aceptando la respuesta en el tick  "aceptar respuesta",  y ¿Por qué no? ¡Darle también un voto positivo! Esto no solo me recomenpensara a mí por la ayuda, si no que hará que la pregunta perdure en el tiempo y le pueda ser de ayuda a personas con el mismo problema que tú en el futuro! Te recomiendo leer [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/vota-pronto-vota-con-frecuencia)